# How to find out MS SQL Server Enterprise Edition Expiration Date?

Tags: sql, version, sql-server-2012, enterprisedb

I have MS SQL Server Enterprise 64bit Install on VMplayer,

Version:   11.0.3128.0
Product LVL:  SP1

Upon installed, there is no documents indicates how long this license will last.

Anyone can tell me a way to find out the expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

This query can help you to get the expiration date of trial version:

```
SELECT
    create_date AS 'SQL Server Install Date',
    DATEADD(DD, 180, create_date) AS 'SQL Server Expiry Date'
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'
```

nt authority/system account is created on the time of installation so you can rely on this as reference point